# Url Rewriting Help

Tags: php, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

This should rewrite any url to index.php?q={url}, and it's working. Anyway, `http://www.domain.com/` just show a blank page. How can I rewrite / to index.php? (`http://www.domain.co.il/index.php` dosen't show a blank page..)

BTW: This code's redirecting and not rewriting, why is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set `DirectoryIndex` in your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```