# How do I get a url to use pretty urls?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Url Rewriting Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660728/url-rewriting-help)

How do I get a url ending in `/index.php?p=2` to display as `/2` instead using `.htaccess` (pretty urls)?

I currently am working on a webcomic displaying site but I have run into a problem with my `.htaccess` file. I am trying to rewrite `/index.php?p=2` to `/2` but for some reason it is not working.

So yeah any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please post what you've tried (your current .htaccess rules).

Comment: you might find this helpful 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394424/make-clean-urls-and-retrieve-query-string

Comment: @limestudios If you are trying to view `/index.php?p=2` when you go to `/2`, then this is a duplicate, which would be my guess.  If you want `/2` to display when you go to `/index.php?p=2`, that would be odd but it's essentially the same rewrite problem with different details.  Voted to close either way.  It might be good if you clarified what you want.

Comment: This "vote to close" war on every **`mod_rewrite`** question has to stop. Yes, questions will be similar, but it doesn't add to the signal-to-noise ratio of the site and may actually help someone who is in this exact scenario (which is different than questions linked). @Levi Morrison

Comment: @AndrewMoore I don't vote to close every `mod_rewrite` question.  But this one is pure generic.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093190/simple-mod-rewrite for a question that is almost identical.  As a side note, I meant to close this as a duplicate of that question, but when I clicked to see what question had already been linked I forgot to change it back.  Not much I can do about it at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an .htaccess file similar to this one... (the flags may need to be modified/varied per mod rewrite flag documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/flags.html)

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

`.htaccess` can't rewrite `/index.php?p=2` into `/2`. **You are approaching the problem in reverse.**

Rewrite rules tells Apache to do something when fetching a specific URI. What you really need to do is tell Apache to "rewrite" a request to `/2` so that it fetches `/index.php?p=2` instead. You can do so with the following `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+)$    index.php?p=$1    [L]
```

and then change, in your HTML, every single link to point to the rewritten URI instead of the canonical one. Apache will not "rewrite" your links for you. It will however, with the help of the rule above, fetch the proper resources when the client queries for `/2`.